# How do you replace only partial string with re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have the text:

```
text = 'Washington state Washington DC"
```

I want my new output to be

```
'WA state Washington DC'
```

I've tried

```
re.sub('Washington(\s[^DC])', 'WA ', text)
```

and get the following output that drops the first letter of "state":

```
'WA tate Washington DC'
```

Basically, I want every instance of "Washington" to be changed to "WA" as long as it doesn't precede "DC". I'm sure there is a really easy way to do this and my brain just doesn't feel like working today! (I'm using Python 3.x) Please help! Thanks

Comment: You can use either `\bWashington state\b` replace with `WA state` or `\bWashington(?! +DC)` replace with `WA`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead like this:

`Washington(?!\s*DC)`

It will check if washington is followed by any number of spaces and "DC"

Comment: `re.sub('Washington(?!\s*DC)', 'WA ', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Can you explain what you mean by negative look ahead? What does the "?!" part of the pattern mean? Thanks again!

Comment: Basically: go find a match (Washington) and look ahead and check if there is the second match (DC) if both are found toss it out and move on. It's perfect for "find x where not followed by y" situations. Don't forget to mark the question as answered 
if its resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Question. It let me hone my relatively new Python skills. There are many ways to do this. I like this way:

```
import re

wa = "Washington state Washington DC"

regexp  = r'Washington\s'
regexp1 = r'WA(\s+DC)'
text    = re.sub(regexp, 'WA ', wa)
text2   = re.sub(regexp1, 'Washington DC', text)
print(text2)
```

Basically, it changes all the occurrences of 'Washington' to 'WA' and then changes back all occurrences of 'WA DC' to 'Washington DC'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
text = ["Washington state Washington DC", "the great state of Washington", "Lives in Washington DC", "I live in Washington State"]
new_text = [re.sub('Washington(?!\sDC)', 'WA', i) for i in text]
```

Output:

```
['WA state Washington DC', 'the great state of WA', 'Lives in Washington DC', 'I live in WA State']
```

Test cases:

```
text = {"Washington state Washington DC":"WA state Washington DC", "the great state of Washington":"the great state of WA", "Lives in Washington DC":"Lives in Washington DC", "I live in Washington State":"I live in WA State"}
for a, b in text.items():
   assert re.sub('Washington(?!\sDC)', 'WA', a) == b, "failed"
print("passed")
```

Output:

```
passed
```